# how to copy a file from local pc to remote using remote credentials powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to copy a file from my local pc and paste it to the remote computer but i am getting logon error. if i use the invoke command with -credential parameter than it works, but first i would like to copy the files from local to the remote server. here is my code

```
$pwd = convertto-securestring "password1234" -asplaintext -force
$cred=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist  
".\Administrator",$pwd

$localpath = "C:\_Projects\test.ps1"
$destination = "\\my ip\c$\_Projects\Deployments\"
copy-item -path $localpath -destination $destination -recurse -Force -Credential $cred
```

Comment: for example if i put a sample file on remote server and use invoke command from my local pc it runs the sample script on remote pc, but copy-item is not working

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Double check the password and ports.